# How to use containerRelativeFrame with padding in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios17, xcode15

I am trying to create consistent width dimensions of a rectangle using `containerRelativeFrame`.  The proportions work great but I don't seem to be able to get it away from using the entire screen real estate.  I would think it would inherit the width and height from it's parent HStack.  Here is my example code.  Note that it does not respect the padding I have provided.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 6, span: 2, spacing: 4.0)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 6, span: 2, spacing: 4.0)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 6, span: 1, spacing: 4.0)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 6, span: 1, spacing: 4.0)
        }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            .padding(40)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Here is what I get in the preview pane.

[image]

How can I get this padding applied before it sizes the rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

[You could write like this, but the padding does not work in this case as well. Because containerRelativeFrame divides the whole view on the given number of sections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPKgt.png)

[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPKgt.png)

```
 HStack {
        Group {
            Rectangle()
            Rectangle()
            Rectangle()
            Rectangle()
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 8, span: 1, spacing: 4.0)
    }
```

//        .padding(.horizontal, 50)